# Remove single quotes from items in list, but leave the brackets

Tags: python-3.x, list, formatting

I need help formatting output of revenues on my code for a homework assignment (we are allowed to use outside help). I want to keep the brackets, but remove single quotes. Everything I have tried so far keeps giving me errors.

Here is my code:

```
cities = []

with open ("revenue.txt", "r")as file:
    for line in file:
        col = []
        c_sum=0
        count = 0
        for word in line.split():
            if count> 0:
                c_sum+=int(word)
            count+=1
            col.append(word)
        col.append(c_sum)
        cities.append(col)
    
print("Name".ljust(12, " "),end="")
print("Revenue".ljust(27, " "),end="")
print("Total".ljust(7, " "),end="")
print("Average".ljust(75, " "),end="")


for i in range(0,len(cities)):
        print (str(cities[i][0]).ljust(12," "),end="")
        print (str(cities[i][1:5]).ljust(27," "), end ="")    #this section formats revenues***
        print(str(cities[i][5]).ljust(7," "),end="")
        print (str("{:.2f}".format(row[i][5]/4.0).ljust(75," ")),end="")
        
sort1 = sorted(cities,key=lambda x: x[1])
print("\n\nSort the cities by their Quarter 1 revenues.")
print([Q1[0] for Q1 in sort1])

sort2 = sorted(cities,key=lambda x: x[3])
print("\nSort the cities by their Quarter 3 revenues.")
print([Q3[0] for Q3 in sort2])

sort3 = sorted(cities,key=lambda x: x[5])
print("\nSort the cities by their total revenues.")
print([totalRev[0] for totalRev in sort3])
```

Here is my current output:

```
Name        Revenue                    Total  Average 
Alabaster   ['40', '50', '23', '18']   131    32.75
Anniston    ['56', '78', '34', '11']   179    44.75
Athens      ['40', '34', '18', '30']   122    30.50
Auburn      ['55', '67', '23', '11']   156    39.00
Decatur     ['44', '23', '56', '11']   134    33.50
Florence    ['55', '67', '33', '23']   178    44.50
Gadsden     ['45', '67', '54', '77']   243    60.75                                                                      

Sort the cities by their Quarter 1 revenues.
['Alabaster', 'Athens', 'Decatur', 'Gadsden', 'Auburn', 'Florence', 'Anniston']

Sort the cities by their Quarter 3 revenues.
['Athens', 'Alabaster', 'Auburn', 'Florence', 'Anniston', 'Gadsden', 'Decatur']

Sort the cities by their total revenues.
['Athens', 'Alabaster', 'Decatur', 'Auburn', 'Florence', 'Anniston', 'Gadsden']
```

need it to look like this:

```
[40, 50, 23, 18]
.
.
.
# and so on
```

Hopefully theres an easy fix! Thanks:)

Comment: Try `print(str([int(i) for i in cities[i][1:5]]).ljust(27," "), end ="")`

Comment: @AndrejKesely It worked. Thanks so much!